# Processing TSV files

Tags: javascript, java, heroku, encoding, google-sheets

I'm working on a project that takes in TSV files, processes it, and then outputs a response. My friend and I use Heroku and Spark to turn our Java-based program into a web app.

Currently, our web application works with only certain .tsv files while others do not and I believe this is some sort of issue that has to do with the specific encoding of .tsv files.

Our **intended input file** is a .tsv file generated from a Google Sheets document but currently, our program cannot parse it correctly. **However**, if we copy and paste the data on that google sheet into a text file and save it as a .tsv then our program is successfully able to process it. Which is weird because both files have the same exact content and textual format but one doesn't work while the other does.

This is my sendData() JS function that is called when a button is clicked:

```
function sendData() {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = function(event) {
            var result = event.target.result;
            $.post("/rides", result, function(result, error) {
                result = result.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
                $(".result").html(result);
            });
        };
        var rides = $("#rides");
        var files = rides[0]['files'];
        var file = files[0];
        fr.readAsText(file, 'ASCII');
    }
```

Here is where it takes in and reads the request through Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    port(getHerokuAssignedPort());
    staticFileLocation("/public");
    get("/ping", (req, res) -> "pong");
    post("/rides", (req, res) -> {
        System.out.println("parsing...");
        final RawParticipants participants = parser.parseInitialRequest(req.body());
        final AssignedRides result = orchestrator.orchestrateRides(participants);
        System.out.println(participants);
        return result.toString();
    });
}
```

The output varies with different .tsv files, but all the ones downloaded from Google Sheets can never be properly parsed. **Either our program cannot read anything in the file from Google Sheets, or it can read some lines but it can't read others. Keep in my there's nothing special about the data. Just plain-text separated by tabs.** I looked into how Google Sheets encodes their .tsv files and it doesn't appear to be anything special just ASCII encoding which is the same with the .tsv files created from copy/paste. So I'm just a little stumped as to how to fix this problem especially when I can input a .tsv file with the same exact info, just generated differently, and have my program successfully read it.

Does anyone know why it can't process certain .tsv files and what could be the solution? Thanks! I'd be more than willing to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Have you tried something like `new String(req.bodyAsBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead of `req.body()`?

Comment: Does the problem happen locally, or only on Heroku?

Comment: @codefinger Just tried your suggestion, sadly it didn't work. The app still can't properly parse a Google Sheets generated .tsv file. In regards to your second question, I'm not entirely sure what you mean but if anything, I don't believe the problem resides with Heroku. Somehow my program simply can't read certain .tsv files due to their encoding and I'm just stumped. I've written unit tests to make sure my parser is working correctly and it successfully parses text separated by tabs. But when it encounters a .tsv file from Sheets, it just goes haywire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stuck on this problem a while back, but I have managed to fix the issue. The reason why .tsv file parsing was not correctly working was due to CRLF line terminators which were generated by Google Sheets when downloading off the website. This is, in some ways, an encoding error but it doesn't need to be solved with much in-depth file editing. All I needed to do was replace "/r/n" with the regular "/n" to denote new lines in the .tsv files. Those line terminators were placed at the end of each line and messed with the proper reading of the file. Thus, in order to fix this, I just had to replace them with default notation for newlines that I use: "/n". Voila! Fixed.